# Mutability of Typescript interface instances (objects)

Tags: javascript, typescript, memory

I've found interfaces to be super useful, but as I need to start optimizing my app due to memory problems I've realized that I don't really understand how they work internally.

Say I have

```
interface Foo {
  bar: number
}
```

And I instantiate some variable with this typing:

```
let x : Foo = { bar: 2 }
```

**Q1**: Does this create a new object?

Now, let's say I want to change the value of bar. I do it one of two ways. First way:

```
x = { bar: 5 }
```

**Q2**: Does this first way create a new object and replace the old object referenced by `x`, causing the old object (with `bar = 2`) to eventually be garbage collected?

Second way:

```
x.bar = 5
```

**Q3**: Does this not create a new object, and instead just updates the value of `bar` in the first object (which had `bar = 2`) and avoids garbage collection since there is still only one object and it's in use?

I believe the answers to my questions are Yes, Yes, and Yes. But I want to be sure since I'm having a real headache dealing with overly-frequent garbage collection and I think the fact that many parts of my code use the "first way" instead of the second may be a big contributing factor.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your answers (Yes, Yes, and Yes) are correct. And if you're replacing objects with new ones (`x = {bar: 5}`) a **lot**, then yes, that will mean that the garbage collector has more work to do compared with doing `x.bar = 5` instead.

Re Q2: `x = {bar: 5}` creates a new object and means the old object referenced by `x` is available for garbage collection **if** nothing else still has a reference to the old object that `x` referred to. Otherwise, if something still has a reference to what `x` used to refer to, e.g.:

```
let y = x;
x = {bar: 5};
```

...then the object `x` used to refer to will stick around (since `y` refers to it) until/unless `y` no longer refers to it (because you assign a different value to `y` or because `y` goes out of scope and isn't referenced by a closure).